# Vb maths calculations incorrect results

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to calculate the expected "score" for a given player in an elo system*.

The problematic line of code is as follows:

```vb
expected(0) = (1 / (1 + (10 ^ (1000 - 1000) / 400)))
```

When I return the value of `expected(0)` directly after this line as a msgbox in a windows forms application, it states the value to be `11` even though it should be `1` (`expected(1)` is declared as an array of integers).

When I run this same line of code in a console application, it returns `1`.

Is there any reason why this line of code is instead returning `11`?

Edit: The exact code of the subroutines for both the console application that I tested (which returns correct value) and the forms application:

Forms:

```vb
Dim expected(1) As Integer
expected(0) = (1 / (1 + (10 ^ (1000 - 1000) / 400)))
Msgbox(expected(0))
```

Console:

```vb
Dim t(1) As Integer
t(0) = (1 / (1 + (10 ^ (1000 - 1000) / 400)))
Console.WriteLine(t(0))
Console.ReadLine()
```

The above numeric values (e.g. 400, 1000) are literally written in to the program like that, as I was just testing whether they work.

*you can look up the equation on the wikipedia page "Elo rating system" but I don't think it is important in this situation. In this situation I am simulating both players Elo being 1000.

Comment: Set `Option Strict On` and possibly post the actual code that generates those values.

Comment: I have to change a lot of things in my entire program if I set Option Strict On but I'll edit to show the code.

Comment: Then you most probably have a lot of things in your app that are not reliable.

Comment: Okay but how does that option affect the above code?

Comment: It doesn't. What you have or the proper `t(0) = CInt((1 / (1 + (10 ^ (1000 - 1000) / 400))))` don't reproduce that result. I doubt this is your real code and those the real values, also because this: `(10 ^ (1000 - 1000)` is just `1`, I don't see why you would have all that stuff to just add `1`. Those value are probably coming from *somewhere* else, in a different form.

Comment: Email me your Windows code, and I will be happy to look into it. Getting 11 is impossible.

Comment: @Jacob I test on a form application, and it correctly return 1. How did you get '11' in your test?

Comment: @XingyuZhao, it would be nice to show the code for how did you get "1".

Comment: @Jimi those values are literally written in the program exactly how I posted above; they aren't declared anywhere they're just numbers. The reason I have all that to just add 1 is because those values should be variables, but they weren't working so I changed them to "1000" to test it, and found it still didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies to anyone who was scratching their head at this, but the solution was very simple and the problem was 100% my fault. As it turns out `msgbox(expected(0)` was actually written as `msgbox("expected 1" & expected(0))` which came out in the box as "expected 11" rather than "1" or "expected 1 1". I thought 11 was the value. Apologies again.

Comment: I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can click '✔' to mark your reply as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula from Wikipidia is:

[image]

One way to code this accurately:

```
Dim d1 As Double = (Rb - Ra) / 400R            '0
Dim d2 As Double = 1 + System.Math.Pow(10, d1) '2
Dim EA As Double = 1 / d2                      '0.5
```

Your expression:

```
   (1 / (1 + (10 ^ (1000 - 1000) / 400)))
```

Is not an accurate translation of the source forumul above, your expression above returns zero instead of 0.5. If EA is an integer, value you will get the same result from both calculations, but I think you should always get the correct value then explicitly manipulate it rather manipulating it implicitly (by the compiler, for instance).